# How to prove this convergence of a sum

Tags: probability, limits

How dos one prove the convergence of this sum $$e^{-m}\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{(mt)^i}{i!}=e^{m(t-1)}$$.

I'm looking at the solution for a problem about probability generating functions and understand the whole procedure except for this step. How do I calculate this? As you can see the right hand side is the probability generating function of a Poisson variable.

Comment: Substitute $x=mt$ to the Taylor Expansion $e^x=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^i}{i!}$

Comment: Aaa that was much simpler than I thought. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{x^n}{n!}\cdots$$